# Vertical middle align for columns (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to do middle align / vertical align for columns inside row. So here is my code :)

Bootstrap use.

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/Luten/ek4jr1L1/5/)

I was trying to use something like this

```
#row-contact {
display: flex;
align-items: center; }
```

But it's seem not working correctly on mobile - columns aren't stack.

So maybe someone can help me and know what I should change to my code.

It should work on mobile too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to your attempted code:

```
#row-contact {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

What you need to do is add a media query for small devices that turns the rows into a `block` element (which occupy 100% of the width by default). I've gone with a width of 600px here, but feel free to adjust to the width that you want the rows to stack on top of each other:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #row-contact {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

I've created a fiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/x7newpsv/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I didn't think it would be so easy. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Does it look like the desktop version on mobile? If so, you might have forgotten:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

In your HTML header.